# Pluggable Database Admin Tools in Swing

Tags: java, swing

Does anyone know of any established database admin tools that one can easily plug into a swing application? Much like any database admin tools, you should be able to "load database", "browse database", "view table" that sort of thing.

Comment: Consider using [`SquirrelSQL`](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) or making your program a [plugin](http://www.squirrelsql.org/index.php?page=plugins).